# MYSQL BLOB Storage html data. In separate table or not?

Tags: mysql, blob

I have table with 100000 of rows. This table also contains a BLOB field, so the table size is around 1GB. This table is scanned regularly by many queries in the application. The blob field is used only in one select query .  This table also contains 5 index with size 10MB. My Doubts are.

1 ) Is it better to move the blob filed to another tables? Will this improve the speed of read operation from table?

2)  The BLOB filed is used to store HTML data about 6 Kib in size. Is BLOB type apt for this?

Comment: Which storage engine are you using?

Comment: Your question is **VERY** vague. Why have the blob? What does that table contain? Is it normalized? ... So -1 for that

Comment: It is normalized table with MyISAM storage engine.

Comment: Please at least give us an inkling as to the structure of the database. It is impossible to say as to how the data is stored and how it is used. All you are going to get is wild gusessed from this message board.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the schema:

- Store images in application server and store relative path of those images. this will result less overhead
- Moving the blob field to another table can also be a good idea.

Why you are keeping html data in blob? are you seriously storing the image styles/css with this? Not recommended at all!

Comment: From my reading of the question, only HTML is being stored in the data. This sounds like a CMS type of thing and is not uncommon at all.

Comment: This BLOB field contains only HTML data + images (This field is used to store HTML of some certificates send to users)

Comment: I concur with Mayukh and generally recommend against storing images in the DB when there is a perfectly good filesystem for such things.